# Webpage loading scrolled part-way down

Tags: javascript, html, css

An odd behavior just popped up on one particular page on my site. While the page is loading, no matter what way you visit the page (refresh, direct input, SERP click, etc) the viewframe is by default partially scrolled down - about 1/5 of the way, just enough to obscure the header. In Chrome, once the peripherals are done loading (analytics and Facebook Graph) the page jerks back to the top. In Firefox, it stays scrolled down even after the page is completely loaded.

Has anyone experienced this before? I tried removing all of my scripts and analytics - this made the load faster, but the scroll issue still remained. I don't have any complicated scripts that could be causing this.

Comment: you said you removed all your scripts and still the scroll was there? could you please share your CSS?

Comment: Jose's solution would provide a reasonable workaround, but I'm afraid I have no idea why this would be occurring in the first place!

Comment: I went through the code piece by piece and it turns out it's an inline Adsense block that's causing the scroll. I've never seen this happen before, but it's definitely the problem - if you remove the block, the scroll issue disappears.

Comment: That's interesting, I would really like to see the page, probably giving the adsense a different property values via CSS would solve the issue.

Comment: <td>
    <script type="text/javascript"><!--
    google_ad_client = "ca-pub-xxxxxxxx";
    google_ad_slot = "xxx";
    google_ad_width = 336;
    google_ad_height = 280;
    //-->
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js"></script>
</td>

Comment: That's not useful... we need to see the page so we can inspect the generated content. Or at least a fiddle with the Adsense would help.

Comment: I finally found it - it wasn't the adsense code itself causing the problem. The ad block pushed an autofocusing form below the fold, which caused the page to immediately scroll down to the form then back up with the page finished loading. When I removed the ad block the form floated back above the fold and the behavior stopped. Very odd.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`window.scrollTo(0,0);` on window load?

Comment: This hack would have worked if I did'nt find the root of the problem, so I'll accept.

Comment: Glad you found a solution! Ciao! :)

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else you may want to consider commenting out `<meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width'>` from your header. I was having this issue with my wordpress website and I was cursing wordpress as I thought it was a css loading through javascript problem. It would load properly one or two times and then other times when loading from cache (fast) it would cause this problem.

I commented out the following from the header

```
<meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width'>
```

as in I removed it. It did not affect the pages styling so it wasn't an problem at all. Its fixed the issue it seems for me.